# php, how do i render 100 items in 10 rows and 10 columns

Tags: php, html, css

So i have an array which contains a hundred seats or sometimes 150, I want to render the items inside but with 10 rows, instead of 1 row and 100 items, how do I do that?

```
  <div class="container">
    <ol>
<-- ROW 1 START--> 
        <li class="row">
            <ol class="seats" type="A">
                <li class="seat">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="A1" />
                    <label for="A1">A1</label>
                </li>
            </ol>
        </li>
<-- ROW 1 End--> 
<-- ROW 2 START--> 
        <li class="row">
            <ol class="seats" type="A">
                <li class="seat">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="A1" />
                    <label for="A1">B1</label>
                </li>
            </ol>
        </li>
<-- ROW 2 END--> 
    </ol>
</div>
```

Here are the php code

```
<?php
require "includes\header.php";
require "includes\database.inc.php";

if (!isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
    header("Location: login.php?error=not_login");
    exit();
}
// SELECT * FROM seats where branch_id = 1
$seats = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM seats where branch_id = 1") or die($mysqli->error);
?>

  <head>
    <link href="./css/seats.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>


  <div class="container">
    <ol>
        <li class="row row--1">
            <ol class="seats" type="A">
            <?php 
                $i=1;
                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($seats)) {
            ?>
                <li class="seat">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="A1" />
                    <label for="A1"><?php echo $row['row'].$row['number'] ?></label>
                </li>
                <?php } ?>
        <li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

but it gives me this UI, which is wrong and not what I want, and when I checked the A3, it highligthed the A1 instead...

[image: Wrong UI and wrong checked ui]

Comment: I think you want to show 10 items per row rather than showing all 100 items in one row. You can create a new ol after 10 items such that it will show next in new rows.

Comment: but my array contains 100 items, how do I do that?

Comment: what kind of data are you storing?

Comment: I am getting the data from the database, it is from a table. which has an id, name, etc

Comment: I'd use a [table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table) instead of ordered lists. Where is your PHP code?

Comment: Just edited it @kerbholz

Comment: make sure the `id` on the input as its label are unique for each input field, else it will all just select the first element in the DOM. Might want to echo the same vars are you do on the label, in both the `id` and `for`.

Comment: @ThomasScheffer thanks! I've fixed that, but I still cant to render it to 10 rows and 10 columns

Comment: Have you tried using grid or flexbox? ie. Just set `display: flexbox;` on your `ol` and give it a width. And give each input field a width of 10%. Tweak where necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can end your ordered list and recreate a new after after every 10 items. Try the code below this might help you to achieve the same:

```
<div class="container">
    <ol>
        <li class="row row--1">
            <ol class="seats" type="A">
            <?php 
                $i=1;
                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($seats)) {
            ?>
                    <li class="seat">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="A1" />
                        <label for="A1">A1</label>
                    </li>
            <?php if ($i%10 == 0) { ?>
                    </ol>
                    <ol class="seats" type="A">
            <?php }
                  $i++;
                }
            ?>
            </ol>
        </li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

Just replace your static data with the dynamic one you fetched from db in $row.

Comment: I think you forgot to increas $i

Comment: sir, I posted the wrong syntax, can you do the one edited instead?

Comment: You should also give unique id to each checkbox input element and also change for attribute of label according to the id. Currently you are giving same id to all and that's why it is checking the same checkbox.